# Same question asked on stackoverflow and magento.stackexchange

Tags: discussion

Following a bout of deja vous I noticed these two questions are posted by the same asker.

- [How Do I exclude a Magento category from the main menu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40584/how-do-i-exclude-a-magento-category-from-the-main-menu)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438115/how-do-i-exclude-a-magento-category-from-the-main-menu

Should they be merged into one?  Which site gets the combined question?  The two questions elicit different answers, perhaps because different people visit the two sites, so are both questions actually valid?

Answer (score 1):

This is not so easy. As long as this website is in beta (and might never get out of it) it is not possible to move the question for SO to here. So no simple *einfach* solution here.

Comment: One of my questions got moved here, so it's obv. possible.

Comment: but only from stackexchange/stackoverflow moderators, not from us

Comment: Right. The migration has to be initiated by moderator of  sender website.